# Teradatabase SQL Assistant foreign key

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

I have created a table called 'customer' on TERADATA-SQL-ASSISTANT.

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
customerid   CHAR(8)                   NOT NULL,
firstname    VARCHAR(20)              NOT NULL,
lastname     VARCHAR(20)              NOT NULL,
email        VARCHAR(20)             NOT NULL,
creditno       INT                    NOT NULL,
phoneno        INT                    NOT NULL,
dateabo     DATE FORMAT 'YY/MM/DD'    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(customerid),
FOREIGN KEY (customerid) REFERENCES WITH CHECK OPTION membership (membershipid));

INSERT INTO customer VALUES('AAAA','Brooks','Swarng','Brooks@gmail.com','706994253476882810','608851734',' 200202','Basic');
```

This is my code so far it executes without errors but the problem is that the FOREIGN KEY membershipid from membership table does not show on my column of the table CUSTOMER. So when I try to insert my data into the table customer it says  // ''[Teradata Database] [3535] A character string failed conversion to a numeric value.''
And my membershipid  still does not appear on the customer table as a column.

--Basic is part of membership table from column membershipid.
Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT when you're asking for *free help* to solve *your problem*. Thanks. It's also pretty difficult to help when you talk about trying to INSERT your data when you don't include the SQL that is trying to do that INSERT.

Comment: I apologize I was not shouting. When coding in SQL it is much easier to understand with all caps. I just wanted to make that clear that your help means a lot. Thanks for the advice I will post the insert code.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the CAPS in the SQL. I was talking about the ALL CAPS TITLE that I edited for you. You can see the edits I made in the question [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62096361/revisions). Also, if you make future changes, please format your code properly. I've done it for you twice now, so you have examples of how to format it already by looking at the edits I made.

Comment: Okay, THANK YOU!

Comment: You are defining a table-level FOREIGN KEY constraint using the existing customerid column. If you want a membershipid column you need to explicitly define one (and either change the table-level constraint definition or use a column-level constraint).

Comment: membershipid CHAR(8) NOT NULL,

FOREIGN KEY ( membershipid ) REFERENCES WITH CHECK OPTION membership (membershipid));

Thank you Fred I solved it.

Comment: `Thank you Fred I solved it` Consider writing up an answer to your own question - there even is a badge for well-received self-answers.